# Using ansible playbook to edit config file inside running docker container

Tags: docker, ansible, containers

I want to edit the configuration file(any application specific/service ) inside running docker container using ansible playbook.I have searched and found few ansible modules/plugins for the docker_image and docker_service which can be used to  handle docker images and containers. But Is there any module available to edit the files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `python` executable inside your container and run ansible on the same host as Docker daemon, you can use `docker` connection plugin to run tasks inside your containers. Test it like this:

```
ansible all -c docker -i 'mycontainer,' -m copy -a 'content=hello dest=/tmp/world'
```

Comment: this is to copy the files inside container right ? is there any way to edit the config parameter inside config file , like lineinfile and  replace?

Comment: Yes, you can use any module.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer konstantin. how do i  edit the config files in remote docker container ?

Comment: I'm afraid no easy ways for that.

Comment: That's what i also thought, i couldn't find any  such reference in the docker documents.